# How to fill an object with curve/splines using Geometry Nodes?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

Such effects are possible by using Extra curves addon (Add > Curve > Knots > Bounce Spline] and by animation nodes add-on (As explained in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3CwKkiJZN0 )

As the Geometry Nodes was added into Blender 2.92+, I was thinking if such results are achievable using Geometry nodes?

This can be theoretically done by these methods:

In the geometry node, create a "Point distribution node" and then derive the "Position" attribute of Control points of a curve, using the "Position" attribute of the Points created using aforementioned "Point Distribution Node".

If Geometry Nodes do not allow manipulation of Curve's control points procedurally then a line with adequate number of verts can be used to fill in the edges between the points created in method 1 by a similar transfer of position attribute from points to verts of the "line" object. This can then be smoothed out using Subdiv node. Then, a "Skin Modifier" followed by "Subdiv surface" modifier can lead to a similar visual result.

The problem is that Blender Geometry node system seems not to allow transfer of attribute from one object [curve or line] to another object [the main object to be filled e.g. Suzanne]

[image: Suzanne Filled with Curves]

Comment: you forgot to mention it's also possible with Sverchok ;)

Comment: Yes, there are mmultiple ways of doing things. But the question is, can it be done in Geo nodes?

Comment: AFAIK in the moment it cannot be done "only" by geometry nodes. But there are some workarounds...

Comment: @Chris. Please share those workarounds